# Net Testing Framework and Repetition

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, nunit, xunit

What is the proper test protocol in writing test cases for data warehouses?

**Background:**

We are copying multiple SQL tables from Source A to Source B, with a special procedure which applies dynamic SQL. The procedure finds the columns in Table A with information_schema. columns, validate if they exist in Table B, then copy.

What is the proper unit testing framework? We have over 1000 tables, do we need to individually test this procedure for 1000 tables validating counts and values? and write 1000 Nunit/Xunit tests in VS Test Explorer?

Eg; Copying SQL table  (Customers, Payments, Inventory).

Customer A ---> Customer B

Inventory ---> Inventory B

Payments B ---> Payments B

Example: run test cases validating count, and copy results into data test table, into, using for/while loop

```
insert into dbo.TestResultTable(TestFlag)
utilize for loop   -- make sure counts are equal for every copy
set @TestFlag = (select count(*) from CustomerA = select count(*) from CustomerB)
set @TestFlag = (select count(*) from InventoryA = select count(*) from InventoryB)
set @TestFlag = (select count(*) from PaymentsA = select count(*) from PaymentsB)
```

Comment: Looks like your code is mostly sql. Try testing framework for sql: [https://tsqlt.org/](https://tsqlt.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are describing a level of testing that is broader than unit tests. I'll come back to that at the end.

You want to verify that an operation completed for 1000 tables and that everything is correct. This is a very high-level test... I'd call it an integration test. That's OK but obviously it's very time consuming.

What I would do to reduce the time is

1. Have a brief test that every table, which should be created, was actually created.
2. Randomly select `n` tables for a complete test.
3. Add further tests based on errors that come up in the future.

Ideally, I'd parameterize `n` and allow for exhaustive testing when needed. For example, the random testing would not catch a problem that arises when some name has a space in it, but this is an unlikely occurence.

Now let's suppose you actually want unit tests for all this (I would)...

1. Put your data layer behind an interface, which you can mock.
2. Create a method that updates 1 table. Test that method exhaustively, using the mock.
3. Now mock the object containing that method.
4. Test that the method is called the requisite number of times, with the correct table names, when you are doing your complete copy.